# Allow more character options in tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

Right now the sidebar says that the allowed characters for tags are:

> tag characters: [a-z 0-9 + # - .]

Is it possible to extend this to support other characters? As the Stack-Exchange network gets bigger, more and more use-cases seem to appear for additional characters.

For example, the "!" character could be useful for web applications ([this company](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!) is called "Yahoo!", not "yahoo" ) and for gaming ([this game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars!) is named "Stars!").

Comment: While I don't disagree in principal, can you say that having "yahoo!" vs "yahoo" would greatly increase your ability to find what you're after? (the main purpose of tags)  That's where I question *how* valuable allowing more characters would be, maybe there are some better examples where the difference is more important?

Comment: @Nick the second example, "Stars!", is a bit better. Still, you have a point, and currently I do not have better examples.

Comment: What about "D&D" (rpg.se)?

Comment: In addition to D&D, RPG.se also includes RPGs such as M&M (Mutants & Masterminds), T&T (Tunnels & Trolls), C&C (Castles & Crusades), and a few minor ones. All of these are fairly popular in the gaming world, so that stack exchange would certainly benefit from an ampersand being allowed.

Comment: This seems mostly relevant for i18n. Diacritics and non-Latin characters aren't optional.